# Remix Console shows all transactions 'pending' even though everything seems to execute correctly

Tags: remix

It seems like my contract gets deployed, I'm able to execute transactions on it but console shows everything as 'pending'

When I deploy my contract:

```
  creation of TestContract pending ..
```

When I invoke a tranasactional method on the deployed/pending contract:

```
 transact to TestContract.testMethod pending ..
```

I can verify with a view method that the transaction actually completes successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Thats exactly what should happen! After a couple seconds (or longer based on transaction fee and network), you should recieve the transaction data.

Sometimes when you cancel a transaction it will still show the pending but never execute the transaction. But otherwise the transaction should work.

Comment: It's been 11 hours an I haven't seen anything other than pending. Also it wasn't like that initially. The console would show the message with pricing&gas almost instantly. Btw. I'm using Remiv VM (London) as my EVM.

Comment: Hmmmm @Ya. I use my metamask to create transactions. I wonder if the VM makes a difference.